# disable UIPageViewController gesture recognizer while in Handing longPressed gesture

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIPageViewController and each Page contains multiple UIViews on the page, each UIView allows Pan gesture after a longPress gesture, I use the following delegate in the contentVC, but it appears the pageVC doesn't care my restriction below and it continue to flip the page! do I have to do anything to disable the page turning while I am in panning? (the last resort will be setting an variable at the PageVC like a canTurn, and set it to NO while the panning is in action....

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] &&
        [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `-gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` method in the PageVC itself, or if you dont wanna add it in the PageVC itself you could let a delegate handle it

Like:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
   if(someCase)
   {
      return yes;
   }

   return no;
}
```

or

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
   return [delegate shouldHandle:.....];
}
```

Comment: What PageVC? Subclass of PageViewController?

Comment: Yes the subclass of UIPageViewController

Comment: That is never called. Should I set the gestureRecoqnizer delegate first?